# storagefile.OpenStreamForReadAsync return an error

Tags: c#, file, uwp, uwp-xaml, storagefile

**Universal windows platform 10**
TargetFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync() is giving me  an error of "Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" when I try to return the stream

```
public static async void StartReadFile(StorageFile TargetFile)
    {


        var stream = await TargetFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

        ZipArchive z = new ZipArchive(stream);
        var worksheet = z.GetEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
        var sharedString = z.GetEntry("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
    }

 private async  void PickUpFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string content = null;
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        ExcelFileReader.StartReadFile(file);
        if(file != null)
        {
            content = "file is saved";
        }
        else
        {
            content = "no file is saved";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have read access to the file?

Comment: Is the file already open in another program?